# Установить мета-теги

Tags: javascript, jquery

Хочу установить на сайт мета-теги для кнопки "Поделиться". Создаю скрытый элемент `span` с определенным `id`, внутри которого записан текст тега. Сам тег устанавливаю через jQuery таким кодом:

```
jQuery("meta[property='og:title']").attr('content', jQuery(элемент).text());
```

Почему-то не хочет работать.

Comment: Приведите код страницы. Надо убедиться, что такой элемент `jQuery("meta[property='og:title']")` существует и выбирается.

Comment: Я его сам создаю внутри "index.php". Вот, что заметил: мета-теги меняются, если посмотреть через инструменты разработчика, но скрипт кнопки "Поделиться" почему-то берет старые значения, которые были установлены при загрузке страницы.

Comment: Ну так хотя бы выложите этот скрипт кнопки "Поделиться". P.S.: сейчас мне уведомление приходит, так как мы с вами вдвоем беседуем, но лучше указывать мой ник @RussCoder

Comment: @RussCoder, скрипт получаю отсюда: `http://api.yandex.ru/share/`, потом вставляю на страницу, а в `jQuery` меняю meta-теги. Менял их даже непосредственно перед вставкой скрипта - ничего не работает.

Answer (score 1):

Всё потому что динамически эти мета-теги добавлять нельзя, даже при попытке вставить ссылку в соц сети(например вк) будут браться старые значения. Вам необходимо формировать нужные мета-теги при загрузке странице, где они непосредственно указываются в php, я так полагаю.

Answer (score 0):

`meta` тэги считываются соц.сетями без запуска JS скриптов, поэтому заполнение тэгов с использованием jQuery, prototype и даже простым JS не сработает.

Необходимо заносить информацию в `meta` еще на сервере при генерации каждой страницы.